# How can I mock Assembly?

Tags: .net, mocking

Is it possible to mock the `Assembly` class?

If so, using what framework, and how?

If not, how would do go about writing tests for code that uses `Assembly`?

Comment: Tell it "your mother is a hamster, and your father smells of eldeberries"?

Comment: @patros: took me a while to understand...

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: Added an example for Rhino.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[TypeMock](http://www.typemock.com) is very powerful. I guess it can do it. For the other mock frameworks like Moq or Rhino, you will need to use another strategy.

Strategy for Rhino or Moq:

Per example: You are using the ***Asssembly*** class to get the assembly full name.

```
public class YourClass
{
    public string GetFullName()
    {
        Assembly ass = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        return ass.FullName;
    }
}
```

The ***Assembly*** class derived from the interface `_Assembly`. So, instead of using ***Assembly*** directly, you can inject the interface. Then, it is easy to mock the interface for your test.

The modified class:

```
public class YourClass
{
    private _Assembly _assbl;
    public YourClass(_Assembly assbl)
    {
        _assbl = assbl;
    }

    public string GetFullName()
    {
        return _assbl.FullName;
    }
}
```

In your test, you mock `_Assembly`:

```
public void TestDoSomething()
{
    var assbl = MockRepository.GenerateStub<_Assembly>();

    YourClass yc = new YourClass(assbl);
    string fullName = yc.GetFullName();

    //Test conditions
}
```

Comment: It does. Can you explain how would I do it in a "traditional" mock framework (like Moq or Rhino)?

Comment: Oh, I didn't knew about this "hidden" `_Assembly` interface. Thanks. If I did, I wouldn't have asked the question. I guess that if Assembly didn't implement this interface I could have created one myself (`IAssembly`) and write a wrapper that implements it and uses the `Assembly` implementation, is that correct?

Comment: According to Microsoft's documentation `_Assembly` should not be used by managed code (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices._assembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "This interface is for access to managed classes from unmanaged code, and should not be called from managed code."

Answer (score 0):

13 years later, mocking assemblies with Moq seems to work just fine.

```cs
var assembly = new Mock<Assembly>();
assembly
    .Setup(a => a.GetTypes())
    .Returns( new [] { typeof(SomeType), } );
```

Then

```cs
Assert.Contains(typeof(SomeType), assembly.Object.GetTypes());
```